# Group by with no aggregation expresssion is not supported

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need help i am getting an error to the following query on azure sql.

```
SELECT illuminance as illuminance, 
       temperature as temperature, 
       (select to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') from dual) AS Date 
  INTO [PowerBIVisualizationOutput] 
FROM [PowerBIVisualizationInput] 
GROUP BY illuminance, temperature, TumblingWindow(minute,5)
```

Comment: Create the tables at (for example): https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: TumblingWindow(minute, 5) each job should start with a minute to receive message. Must i have to remove this function? But if i dont group by both sensors, i wont be able to view these sensors on the power bi dataset dashboard.

Comment: Stream analysis job in azure sql db. The jobs are working just need to get date for the current timestamp of that specific day. Each time job is executed on portal. Currently the field is there as an empty field on power bi dataset.

Comment: Its basically Stream Analysis in Azure